# Panic Runtime Error index out of range [3] with length 3

Tags: arrays, loops, dictionary, go, slice

Facing an error Panic Runtime Error index out of range [3] with length 3. The below error seems to indicate the index is out of range or length

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [3] with length 3
main.romanToInt(0xc000022080, 0x3, 0x8)
solution.go, line 15
main.__helper__(...)
solution.go, line 30
main.main()
solution.go, line 58
```

```
func romanToInt(s string) int {
    romanNum := map[byte]int{
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000,
    }

    var sum int = 0
    for i := 0; i <= len(s); i++ {
        currentInt := romanNum[s[i]]
        nextInt := romanNum[s[i+1]]
        if currentInt < nextInt {
            sum = sum + (nextInt - currentInt)
            i += 1
        } else {
            sum = sum + currentInt
        }
    }
    return sum
}
```

Error pointing to

```
nextInt := romanNum[s[i+1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you pass the string `XII` to your function. That makes `len(s)` `3`, which means that the body of your loop would (if the panic didn't occur) execute **4** times (when `i` is `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` since your condition is `i <= len(s)`.

On the iteration where `i` is `2` (i.e. it refers to the second `I` in `XII`, the last character), when the line

```
nextInt := romanNum[s[i+1]]
```

attempts to access the next character (`i+1` will be `3`) then it will be out of bounds. Remember, slices/arrays are `0` indexed. This is the reason for the panic.

It's also worth nothing that if the panic did not occur when `i` was `2`, then it would certainly occur during the next iteration where `i` is `3`, since `3` is out of bounds for `s`, on the following line:

```
currentInt := romanNum[s[i]]
```

To fix the issue, you need to reconsider how you approach the condition of the loop. Using `<=` here is likely to cause you a problem. Also, within the body of the loop, you need to consider that when you're looking at the last character in the string, there *is not* a next character, but your code just assumes that there is. Addressing both of these problems should help you overcome the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For i=len(s)-1, the expression s[i+1] accesses the index s[len(s)], which is invalid. The index you are accessing does not exist. Even if you fix it,  your loop range includes len(s), so next time around s[i] will be out of range.